# Script stuck in if statement at elif

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, tkinter

I created a password generator, which creates random passwords out of symbols, numbers and characters. There I have an input, where the user *must* enter a value and it has to be numeric. So I tried to solve this with `elif`. But, even when expected number (`int`) is entered, the loop is still stuck at `elif`. Here my code:

```
def PasswordGenerationFunc():
    password = None
    passwordLength = inputPasswordLength.get()
    userName = inputUsername.get()

    if len(passwordLength) == 0:
        ResultDisplay.configure(text="Length of password is mandatory.", fg="red")
    elif type(passwordLength) != int:
        ResultDisplay.configure(text="Only digits are allowed." + passwordLength, fg="red")
    else:
        passwordLength = int(passwordLength)
        if passwordLength > maxPasswordLength:
            ResultDisplay.configure(text="The limit of password length are 20 characters.", fg="red")
        else:
            if userName != "":
                password = "".join([random.choice(passwordConstructor) for i in range(passwordLength)])
                ResultDisplay.configure(text="Generated password for " + userName + " is:\n" + password, fg="white")
            else:
                password = "".join([random.choice(passwordConstructor) for i in range(passwordLength)])
                ResultDisplay.configure(text="Generated password is: \n" + password, fg="white")
```

In

```
ResultDisplay.configure(text="Only digits are allowed." + passwordLength, fg="red")
```

I print out `passwordLength` to check if wrong values were passed, but was not the case. I am so into the loop, I might ignoring some logic.

Expected behaviour:

- User enters letters, loop stops at `elif`. User enters digits, loop enters `else` condition.

Now:

- User enters digits, loop still stops at `elif`.

Here my full code, so you might understand it better:

```python
# This is a small tool to generate passwords

# IMPORTS
from datetime import datetime
import random
from tkinter import *

# VARIABLES
date = datetime.now()
dateFormat = str(date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
lowerCase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
upperCase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
numbers = "0123456789"
symbols = "!?%&@#+*"
passwordConstructor = lowerCase + upperCase + numbers + symbols
maxPasswordLength: int = 20
bgColor_1 = "black"

# MAKE OUTPUT SELECTABLE

# GENERATE PASSWORD FUNCTION
def PasswordGenerationFunc():
    password = None
    passwordLength = inputPasswordLength.get()
    userName = inputUsername.get()

    if len(passwordLength) == 0:
        ResultDisplay.configure(text="Length of password is mandatory.", fg="red")
    #elif type(passwordLength) != int:
    elif isinstance(passwordLength, int):
        ResultDisplay.configure(text="Only digits are allowed.", fg="red")
    else:
        passwordLength = int(passwordLength)
        if passwordLength > maxPasswordLength:
                ResultDisplay.configure(text="The limit of password length are 20 characters.", fg="red")
        else:
            if userName != "":
                    password = "".join([random.choice(passwordConstructor) for i in range(passwordLength)])
                    ResultDisplay.configure(text="Generated password for " + userName + " is:\n" + password, fg="white")
            else:
                    password = "".join([random.choice(passwordConstructor) for i in range(passwordLength)])
                    ResultDisplay.configure(text="Generated password is: \n" + password, fg="white")


# SCREEN
screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("450x400")
screen.configure(bg="black")
screen.title("PASSWORD GENERATOR")

# TITLE
Title = Label(screen, text="PASSWORD GENERATOR", font=("Arial Bold", 18), fg="green")
Title.configure(bg="black")
Title.pack(pady=20)

# MAIN FRAME
MainFrame = Frame(screen)
MainFrame.configure(bg="black")
MainFrame.pack(pady=5)

# INPUT USERNAME
usernameLabel = Label(MainFrame, text="Please enter username:", font=("Arial Bold", 14))
usernameLabel.configure(bg="black")
usernameLabel.pack()

inputUsername = Entry(MainFrame, font=("Arial Bold", 12))
inputUsername.pack()

# INPUT PASSWORD LENGTH
passwordLengthLabel = Label(MainFrame, text="Please enter length of password:", font=("Arial Bold", 14))
passwordLengthLabel.configure(bg="black")
passwordLengthLabel.pack()

inputPasswordLength = Entry(MainFrame, font=("Arial Bold", 12))
inputPasswordLength.pack()

# GENERATE BUTTON
GenerateBtn = Button(MainFrame, text="GENERATE", font=("Arial", 14), command=PasswordGenerationFunc, bg="black")
GenerateBtn.pack(pady=10)

# DISPLAY RESULT
ResultDisplay = Label(MainFrame, text="", font=("Arial", 14))
ResultDisplay.configure(bg="black")
ResultDisplay.pack(pady=15)

# COPY TO CLIPBOARD BUTTON
#CopyBtn = Button(MainFrame, text="COPY", font=("Arial", 14), bg="black")
#CopyBtn.clipboard_append(password)
#CopyBtn.pack(pady=10)

# WINDOW
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Stuck at if-else? Do you mean the kernel is busy?

Comment: Hi, no the script still runs. But correct behaviour would be:
User enters letters, the loop should stay at elif. If User enters digits (0-9), then loop should enter next if-statement.
Current behaviour:
Whatever the user enters, the loop stops at elif. Even the user input is a digit.

Comment: what is the type of `passwordLength`? If it is the length of a password, then it has to be an integer. Then `if len(passwordLength) == 0:` will give you an error `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`, which it isn't. So, I assume that the `passwordLength` is the length of password stored in a string. In that case `elif type(passwordLength) != int:` this is always true. So, your logic is wrong here. 
Do you know that python user input is always a string and you have to convert the data type as per your need?

Comment: Ask yourself what is the type of `passwordLength` immediate before the `if` statement. It is probably different than what you assume it is. A string of only digits is still a string, not an int.

Comment: I tried following:

Comment: that is what I am saying. If `passwordLength` is an `int` then you will get an error. Since, you said there is no error, so I assume it is a `str`. Which is always true for your `elif`

Comment: As @PrakharSharma said: At that point `passwordLength` is a string because that is what the `get()` method of a tkinter `StringVar` returns (and why the later `type(passwordLength) != int` will always be true.

Answer (score 2):

First, convert the input to `int`.

```py
try:
    passwordLength = int(input("Your message "))
except ValueError:
    print(f"Input is not a valid integer. Please try again.")
```

Modify the if conditions for an integer input as follows:

```py
if passwordLength == 0:
    pass # your output here
else:
    pass # your logic to generate a password
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention that I use tkinter to build a GUI. So therefore the input is an entry. So thats not working.

Comment: I shared my whole code above in my quetion.

Comment: its fine you can put `passwordLength = int(inputPasswordLength.get())`. And inside value error, you print the error in a text box in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

To compare objects and its datatype use `isinstance(object, type)`:

```py
isinstance(3, int) ===> True
isinstance(3, str) ===> False
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. But how do I implement this in code? And the '3' stands for the else condition?

Comment: Hi,
I tried following:
`elif isinstance(passwordLength, str):
        ResultDisplay.configure(text="Only digits are allowed." + passwordLength, fg="red")`

but still stops at elif.

Comment: Hi @David10za but the password will only created, if the loop enters else. So how this going to work?

Comment: @David10za he wants to generate password. The only input is a password length.

Comment: But like I mentioned, password will be only created in else condition:
`else:
                    password = "".join([random.choice(passwordConstructor) for i in range(passwordLength)])
                    ResultDisplay.configure(text="Generated password is: \n" + password, fg="white")`

Comment: follow my answer. There is a logical error in your code.